# Подключение javax.media

Tags: java, maven, изображения

работаю над сравнением фотографий и набрел на сайт [https://web.archive.org/web/20160305150423/http://www.lac.inpe.br/JIPCookbook/6050-howto-compareimages.jsp](http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html)

Хотел попробовать код оттуда, но у меня компилятор начал кричать на

```
import javax.media.jai.InterpolationNearest;
import javax.media.jai.JAI;
import javax.media.jai.iterator.RandomIter;
import javax.media.jai.iterator.RandomIterFactory;
import com.sun.media.jai.widget.DisplayJAI;
```

Естественно я пошел на сайт maven и посмотрел dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jai-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Однако почему-то  version выделяет красным цветом.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, как это исправить? И, заодно, если у Вас есть предложения по поводу сравнения двух фотографий, не могли бы Вы предложить что-нибудь?
Просматривал уже [Библиотеку, написанную энтузиастом](http://mindmeat.blogspot.com/2008/07/java-image-comparison.html)

и несколько статей на хабре

Comment: быстрый поиск по mavencentral дает понять, что у вас опечатка в <artifactId/>
Должно быть jai_core, с подчеркиванием

Comment: Да, Вы правы, но все равно, даже с подключением этой библиотеки ругается на данные строки... Пробовал еще подключить `javax.ws.rs`, но также безуспешно

Comment: я пробовал в своем pom.xml подключить jai_core с той же версией - все ОК. Можно попробовать очистить кэш IDE, иногда это помогает. Если у вас IDEA - File - Invalidate Caches/ Restart и снова импортировать проект Maven

Comment: Подключить библиотеку получилось, но результата с исправлением ругательства на данные строки это не дало, к сожалению

Comment: Приведите в вопросе вывод компилятора, о которм идет речь